# Which hive settings require restart?

Tags: hive, configuration, amazon-emr

I was experimenting with some hive options to transform a merge join into a map join but wasn't able to obtain a query plan that would show a map join step. I was setting the options for the Hue session I was in.

With the same options I was experimenting earlier, I launched another EMR cluster the next day and explain plan showed the map join step (on same tables).

Per my understanding some options work only when set in the initial config before hive is started and some work also on a per session-basis.

Is the last statement true, and if yes, where can I find which options take effect when ?

Comment: To begin with, how do you define "Hive" - the Metastore service (possibly in HA)? The HiveServer2 service using MetaStore? The HS2 w/ an embedded Metastore (i.e. no "public" Metastore for Spark, Pig coordination)?

Comment: Also, do you manage a generic `hive-site.xml` for fat clients and services, or do you use specific `hivemetastore-site` and `hiveserver2-site` conf for services?

Comment: I am using AWS EMR. The custom settings I specify at deployment time are stored in hive-site.xml config.